# How to sen file using httpClient in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8, angular-httpclient

I have tried to send file using `HttpClient`:

```
 public async uploadProfile(data: UploadProfile): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.post(this.uploadProfileUrl, data).toPromise();
 }
```

Before sending file I prepare it to binary array:

```
interface UploadProfile {
    file: any;
}


file = [123, 10, 32, 32, 34, 100, 105, 115, 97, 98, 108, 101, 83, 105, 122, 101, 76, 105, 109]
```

But I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:2177)
```

Comment: do you have a httpInterceptor? and whats the value of `this.uploadProfileUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to an undefined url during your request. Try to do the following as a test:

Change:

```
 public async uploadProfile(data: UploadProfile): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.post(this.uploadProfileUrl, data).toPromise();
 }
```

To:

```
 public async uploadProfile(data: UploadProfile): Promise<any> {
    return await this.http.post('http://yourUrl/resource', data).toPromise();
 }
```

If this works and you don't see the error anymore, try to find why `uploadProfileUrl` is undefined when you make the call.